# Process likes for each Facebook friend (multiple JSON requests) quickly

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I had the idea to write a little program which would check every like of a person's Facebook friends. There are presumably other apps that do this, to find your "Perfect Match' and that kind of baloney.

I can find a list of the authorized user's friends, and I can in turn find a list of each friend's interest. I find a friend's likes by accessing the Facebook API, and move on to the next friend.

The problem is that for a person with 1,000 friends, I am accessing the API 1000 seperate time, and I'm not sure if there's a way around this. It's of course, way too slow. Here's my (fairly simple) code so far:

```
if(isset($_POST['array'])){

    //get the posted friends list
    $jsonarray = $_POST['array'];

    //decode from json
    $friendlist = json_decode($jsonarray, true);

    //create variable
    $count = 0;

    //for each friend
    foreach ($friendlist as $friend) {
        //access their list of likes
        $url = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/" . $friend['id'] . "/likes?limit=1000&access_token=TOKENHERE");
        $likes = json_decode($url,true);
        foreach($likes['data'] as $like) {
            $count++;
        }
    }

    //spit this out, ready for script.js to receive
    echo json_encode($count);

} else {

    //spit this out, ready for script.js to receive, still needs to be ajax, that's what script.js is expecting
    echo json_encode("no data");

}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you might be able to offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with one FQL query:

```
select uid, page_id from page_fan where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me())
```

You can execute this via the

```
/fql?q=...
```

endpoint.

Comment: I'll also add that Facebook limits the output to 5000 records, so this way won't work for most people.